# Find the particular solution of a non-homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Usually an homogeneous linear recurrence relation of degree $k$ with $k \in\mathbb{Z}$ of the form

$$u_n = c_1u_{n-1} + c_2u_{n-2} + c_3u_{n-3} + \ldots + c_ku_{n-k}$$

has the characteristic polynomial equation of degree $k$ where each $x$-variable is raised to the power of the corresponding rank assuming $n=k$

$$x^k = c_1x^{k-1} + c_2x^{k-2} + c_3x^{k-3} + \ldots + c_{k-1}x^1 + c_kx^0$$

We know a linear recurrence relation is called non-homogeneous if it is in the form

$$u_n = c_1u_{n-1} + c_2u_{n-2} + c_3u_{n-3} + \ldots + c_ku_{n-k} + f \left(n \right)\quad\text{where}\quad f \left(n \right)\neq 0$$

The solution $\left(a_n \right)$ of a non-homogeneous recurrence relation has two parts.

First part is the solution $\left(a_h \right)$ of the associated homogeneous recurrence relation (obtained by removing the $f \left(n \right)$-part) and the second part is the particular solution $\left(a_t \right)$.

The final solution then have this form

$$a_n = a_h + a_t$$

The solution $\left(a_h \right)$ is determined by solving the characteristic polynomial equation, but what about the particular solution $\left(a_t \right)$?

I am trying to solve the following sequence $\begin{cases}
    u_0 &= 1                \\
    u_n &= 1.5u_{n-1} + 2n
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch (for a solution that does everything at once):

Consider

$$u_n=1.5u_{n-1}+2n$$
and
$$
u_{n-1}=1.5u_{n-2}+2(n-1).
$$

Subtracting these from each other gives
$$
u_n-u_{n-1}=1.5u_{n-1}-1.5u_{n-2}+2
$$
or that
$$
u_n=2.5u_{n-1}-1.5u_{n-2}+2
$$

Therefore,
$$
u_{n-1}=2.5u_{n-2}-1.5u_{n-3}+2.
$$

Subtracting these two gives
\begin{align*}
u_n-u_{n-1}&=(2.5u_{n-1}-1.5u_{n-2}+2)-(2.5u_{n-2}-1.5u_{n-3}+2)\\
&=2.5u_{n-1}-4u_{n-2}+1.5u_{n-3}
\end{align*}
or that
$$
u_n=3.5u_{n-1}-4u_{n-2}+1.5u_{n-3}.
$$

This last equation can be solved using the standard homogeneous recurrence formula.

The characteristic polynomial is then
$$
x^3-3.5x^2+4x-1.5=(x-1)^2\left(x-1.5\right).
$$
Therefore, the general form for $u_n$ is 
$$
u_n=c_1(1)^n+c_2n(1)^n+c_3(1.5)^n=c_1+c_2n+c_3(1.5)^n,
$$
where the constants $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ are to be determined.

Plugging into the first recurrence, we have
$$
c_1+c_2n+c_3(1.5)^n=1.5(c_1+c_2(n-1)+c_3(1.5)^{n-1})+2n
$$
or that
$$
c_1+c_2n=1.5c_1+1.5c_2n-1.5c_2+2n.
$$
Since this equation must be true for any $n$, the corresponding coefficients must be equal.  In other words, the coefficients without $n$'s satisfy 
$$
c_1=1.5c_1-1.5c_2
$$
and the coefficients with $n$ satisfy
$$
c_2=1.5c_2+2.
$$
In other words,
$c_2=-4$ and $c_1=-12$.

Thus, the solution is of the form
$$
u_n=-12-4n+c_3(1.5)^n.
$$
Finally, using the initial value,
$$
u_0=1=-12+c_3
$$
gives
$$
c_3=13.
$$

Putting this all together, the solution to the recurrence is
$$
u_n=-12-4n+13(1.5)^n.
$$

The homogeneous and particular setup here is a little complicated to express, the $(1.5)^n$ would be a solution to the homogeneous (with the initial condition $u_0=1$) and $-12-4n+12(1.5)^n$ is a solution to the particular with $u_0=0$).  If you want to use the homogeneous and particular setup, you must be careful about the initial conditions.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you. The idea is to get rid of the particular part to get the homogeneous polynomial equation.

Comment: Can the same be applied in a generalized way to arithmetico-geometric sequences such as $u_n=1.5u_{n-1}+1$ with the initial condition $u_0=1$?

Comment: I ask this because some books usually solve for $\alpha=1.5\alpha+1$ and construct an auxiliary sequence $v_n=u_n-\alpha$

Comment: Sure, it can be used in general (at least when $f(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$).  You'll need to change the step where you determine the constants as appropriate.

Comment: With the value $\alpha$ used as a pivotal point to construct an auxiliary geometric sequence such that $\left(u_n-\alpha\right)=k\left(u_{n-1}-\alpha\right)$

Comment: Is this method similar to solving for the characteristic polynomial equation of degree 1 in disguise?

Comment: Yes, when $f(n)$ is a polynomial, then the characteristic equation that you'll get using this method will be the characteristic equation of the homogeneous system times $(x-1)^{\deg(f)}$.  So, it is solving the characteristic polynomial equation of degree $1$ in disguise - this can allow you to skip right to the answer and general form.

Comment: For arithmetico-geometric sequences such as $u_n=1.5u_{n-1}+1$ what is the following equation $\alpha=1.5\alpha+1$? It is mentioned as the fixed point value (where the first bisector $y=x$ crosses the line) but more conceptually is it related to finding the corresponding characteristic polynomial?

Comment: You could also apply this method to the question that you asked on November 27th.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the relationship to $\alpha=1.5\alpha+1$.  If you use this method on that recurrence, you'd get $u_n=2.5u_{n-1}-1.5u_{n-2}$ which has characteristic polynomial $x^2-2.5x+1.5=(x-1)(x-1.5)$.  It's not entirely clear how this lines up with the other method, but it might just be a shift of this characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I got this too. That's why I was asking for it. But with the equation $\alpha=1.5\alpha+1$ you can construct an auxiliary sequence $v_n=u_n-\alpha$ using the property that $\left(u_n-\alpha\right)=k\left(u_{n-1}-\alpha\right)$ and then you can find the closed formula.

Comment: I am trying to understand if this $\alpha$-pivot is just a special case for solving arithmetic-geometric first-order linear sequences or if it can be generalized.

Comment: This might deserve a new post. I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Obviously the homogeneous solution is of the form $c\,1.5^n$. Then we can look for a particular solution with a linear form $an+b$.

We have

$$an+b=1.5(a(n-1)+b)+2n$$

and by identification we obtain $a$ and $b$.

> $-4n-12$.